# Python - csv writer write by column, not row

Tags: python, csv

I am processing a series of text files, out of which I want to keep some variables. I am trying to keep these variables in a csv file. Each text file will take 1 row and N columns from this csv file.. I could have 1000 files or more which would result in a csv file with 1000 rows and N columns (N could be 10 or more or less). I am trying to use the following code

```
res=[variable1, variable2, variable3, ..., variableN]
csvfile = "summary.csv"
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(res)
```

The problem is that it writes one value in every row, then moves on to the next row for the next variable.. while I want all variables for each text file to occupy 1 row (and N columns). How should I change my code in order for it to work properly?

EDIT

```
import re
import collections
from collections import Counter
import csv
import sys


wanted1 = re.findall('\w+', open('words1.csv').read().lower())
wanted2 = re.findall('\w+', open('words2.csv').read().lower())
for f in sys.argv[1:]:
    words = re.findall('\w+', open('f').read().lower())
    cnt = Counter()
    cnt1 = 0
    cnt2 = 0
    cntWords = 0
    for word in words:
        cntWords += 1
            if word in wanted1:
                cnt[word] += 1
                cnt1 += 1
            if word in wanted2:
                cnt[word] += 1
                cnt2 += 1   
print cnt1, cnt2, cntWords
res=[cnt1, cnt2, cntWords]
csvfile = "summary.csv"
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(res)
```

In this case each of these variables is a number. I want to also add some variables which will contain a string content. Each text file will occupy 1 row. Each variable will occupy one cell.

For example cnt1 may have the value 10000, cnt2 may have the value 2000, cntWords may have the value 30000 etc.

I tried to change my code to process all .txt files in a folder but now I am getting an error

```
  File "countWords.py", line 29
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
                                                   ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

EDIT 2 : Output.csv should look like that

```
       Column 1 Column 2 Column 3
Row 1: Cnt1     Cnt2     CntWords      (all row 1 values should be derived from file1.txt)
Row 2: Cnt1     Cnt2     CntWords      (all row 2 values should be derived from file2.txt)
Row 3: Cnt1     Cnt2     CntWords      (all row 3 values should be derived from file3.txt)
Row 4: Cnt1     Cnt2     CntWords      (all row 4 values should be derived from file4.txt)
Row 5: Cnt1     Cnt2     CntWords      (all row 5 values should be derived from file5.txt)
Row 6: Cnt1     Cnt2     CntWords      (all row 6 values should be derived from file6.txt)
```

By Cnt1 I mean the value of Cnt1, By Cnt2 I mean the value of Cnt2, By CntWords I mean the value of CntWords (these will be numbers)

```
       Column 1 Column 2 Column 3
Row 1: 5000     3000     10000      (all row 1 values should be derived from file1.txt)
Row 2: 510     420     1423      (all row 2 values should be derived from file2.txt)
```

This means that the input were 2 text files, the first of which had 5000 words of word list 1, 3000 words of word list 2, 10000 total words, while the second text file had 510 words of word list 1, 420 words of word list 2, 1423 words in total.

Comment: It is not clear to me what kind of data is contained in `variable1`, etc. My answer addresses two possibilities here, but it would be helpful if you updated your question to give us sample input data and expected output, as well as the wrong output you are getting now. This doesn't have to be real data, just an example that shows us what is happening and what you wanted instead.

Comment: Ok please wait I will try to update my answer shortly.

Comment: just edited my initial post. thanks

Comment: See, you are doing something *completely different* here. The fact that you are writing out `Counter` objects to a CSV changes what you need to do entirely. What output were you expected here, per counter?

Comment: Sorry for not properly explaining. The counters should be set to zero for every text file, inside the files loop. I have two word lists, and I count the number of words that belong in this word lists for every text file. Then I also calculate the total number of words in every text file. And I want to write these at a summary csv file (each file should occupy one row with N columns, N being the number of variables I want to keep)

Comment: Please *update your question* to include sample output then. An illustration of the output you expect is *far more valuable*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71502/discussion-between-adrcoder-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: Sigh. Your output doesn't show anything helpful. A counter consists of keys (words here) and counts. Did you just want to dump those as representations? I can't imagine `Counter({'word1': 42, 'word2': 21, 'word3': 7})` being very useful.

Comment: I have mostly stopped using the `csv` module of Python and instead use pandas. It has `read_csv` and its DataFrame object has `to_csv`. I would build up a DataFrame with the counts and words and then use `to_csv`.

Comment: @FinnÅrupNielsen: yet using a DataFrame would not solve the actual issue here, which is partly an indentation error and mostly an error in where to collect and write the data to CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you wanted to do was write the 3 counters to a CSV file, then just write to a CSV file *in the loop*. Create your CSV writer outside of the loop and write rows to it as you process files:

```
find_words = re.compile(r'\w+').findall

# create *sets* for faster membership tests
wanted1 = set(find_words(open('words1.csv').read().lower()))
wanted2 = set(find_words(open('words2.csv').read().lower()))

csvfile = "summary.csv"
with open(csvfile, "wb") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)

    for f in sys.argv[1:]:
        cnt1 = cnt2 = cntWords = 0

        with open(f) as inputfile:
            for line in inputfile:
                for word in find_words(line.lower()):
                    cntWords += 1
                    if word in wanted1:
                        cnt1 += 1
                    if word in wanted2:
                        cnt2 += 1   

        writer.writerow([cnt1, cnt2, cntWords])
```

I've also replaced your `wanted*` lists with sets for fast membership tests (rather than scan the whole list each time it'll find words in constant time), and moved to scanning input files line by line to avoid busting memory.

Comment: This code gives me the following error:   File "countWordsLM.py", line 26
    cntWords += 1
           ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block . Also, is there a bracket or sth missing from the last line ?

Comment: Looks good (and much faster with the optimization you're doing). The problem is it puts everything in one column, 550,66,553705 while these numbers should be in separate columns.. any ideas how to change that?

Comment: @adrCoder: those *are* separate columns, with the commas separating the columns. If you need a different column separator, then tell the `csv.writer()` object so.

Comment: shouldn't you get the words of the files to lower or sth as well? Some of the numbers are lower than the ones I was getting previously, are you sure you are counting the words correctly from the lists and the file ? ( words could be small or with caps or whatever, are you checking for these ? maybe the words in open(f) should also be brought down to .lower() ?

Comment: @adrCoder: I missed out a `str.lower()` call, yes.

Comment: I will accept your answer although I wanted to see them in different columns when I open it with Excel or sth. But I think on Excel they separate columns with ; and maybe even put text between " ". I will have to search for it. Thanks ! By the way, the improvement in speed with what you did with the word lists and all that is really impressive. Maybe it is like 5 times faster or something !

Comment: @adrCoder: then tell Excel to use commas as the separator, or use a different CSV dialect.

Comment: Ok I will try to find how to do that, I am not as good as you are so what seems obvious to you is not also obvious for me sometimes, thanks anyways :-P

Comment: @adrCoder: the problem is more that Excel uses *locale specific settings*; I cannot see what settings your machine might use. See https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba for help on how to open CSV files with different delimiters and other settings.

Comment: Yes yes I see. I will have to import these data on another software for some statistical later on so it is really a matter of how to keep then in a format that is both understandable for somebody who reads the file but also in a good enough format to use them for further research. Thanks for your help Martijn !

Comment: By the way, I am using Sublime text 2 on a Mac Os X. I selected Identation Using Spaces and from below " Convert Identation to Spaces". Tab width is currently set to 4. I don't know if these setting are correct and if they are what you suggested I should do earlier. By the way there is still a closing bracket missing in the last line of your code.

Comment: @adrCoder: those are excellent settings. You can also add `"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true` to your settings file (or just to the Python specific settings file).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71611/discussion-between-adrcoder-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 1):

Indentation error in line 18, it must look like

```
csvfile = "summary.csv"
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    for f in sys.argv[1:]:
        words = re.findall('\w+', open('f').read().lower())
        cnt1, cnt2 = 0, 0
        cntWords = len(words)
        for word in words:
            if word in wanted1:
                cnt1 += 1
            if word in wanted2:
                cnt2 += 1
        print cnt1, cnt2, cntWords
        res = [cnt1, cnt2, cntWords]
        writer.writerow(res)
```

P.S. See [example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for Counter usage

Comment: The indentation issue is *not the actual question*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why not? He want write one file in one csv raw.

Comment: Right, the question started out as something completely different; it may well be that the only thing that still remains is the indentation error.

Comment: I want to note that counting words this way counts words dups too

Comment: Hello, i think it needs to be open(f).read().lower()), open('f').read().lower()) gives me an error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "countWordsLM.py", line 14, in <module>
    words = re.findall('\w+', open('f').read().lower())
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'f'. Furthermore, it puts all three variables in one cell, how can we keep cnt1 in one column, cnt2 in another, cntWords in another column etc? At least your code creates a row for each text file so it is a progress indeed

Comment: CSV delimiter defaults to ',' See [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params) for full info